# To display DIV by default if Javascript is disabled in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am showing and hiding a div Via Jquery. Is there any way to display that DIV by default if Javascript is disabled in Browser?

Comment: do you know what css is?

Comment: Don't hide it by default in CSS then.

Comment: make it visible in the markup, hide it with javascript, therefore it will be displayed if js is disabled

Comment: Using css you make display that div. ex. #div{display:block;}@user4956321

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please remember to upvote them and accept the answer that helped you the most to solve your problem!

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove/hide that div with JS code. If no JS is enabled, than code will not be executed:

```js
$('.fallback').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fallback">Fallback if no JS</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<noscript>` block and inside use some CSS to make the specific div show instead of being hidden. The following code has been tested with Javascript disabled and the div shows up properly, but is hidden with Javascript enabled:

```css
#hiddenID {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="hiddenID">test</div>
<noscript>
  <style>
    #hiddenID {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<noscript>` tag :

```
<noscript>
    <div>
        Javascript is disabled.
    </div>
</noscript>
```

If javascript is activated, the div won't be displayed.

More [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp).

Answer (score 0):

use`<noscript></noscript>` tag to display something when javascript is disabled in browser.